# How can I report performance counters for monitoring?

Tags: node.js

I contribute to an open source application that has a series of internal queues (implemented as arrays). Monitoring of these queues is an important part of diagnosing any performance issues.
In other languages, operating systems, I've been able to expose performance counters which can be seen by monitoring tools for a real time view (or to build up historic information).
What's the best way of exposing these in the node/linux ecosystem?
Currently I am logging them to disk through winston, but that creates lots of logging...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pm2 custom metrics](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-metrics/) for that

Comment: They looked really good and I went ahead an implemented them, but it appears they require PM2 plus.  This is an open source project so was really looking for a free solution to being able to 'see inside'

Comment: @JamesBerry PM2+ required for remote diagnostic (using their server for transporting and represent monitoring data), but locally you can use `pm2 monit` for free.

Comment: thanks, I now have this running but doesn't seem to support metrics from node_worker threads (they just don't appear)